# Swift Present Model ViewController Not Showing UINavigationBar?

Tags: swift

My Scenario, I am trying to Implement present model ViewController transition from VC_A to VC_B. Here, VC_B I have embed in Navigation-controller but navigation controller not showing preoperly (I mean without bar tint color). How to fix this?

```
let cropViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cropviewcontroller") as! DDCropViewController
    cropViewController.delegate = self
    cropViewController.image = image
    cropViewController.pointSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: cropViewController)
self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code working fine.

```
// MARK: Navigation Bar Color Apply
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = #colorLiteral
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes =[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below line in presentedViewController(here your VC_B) viewWillApear method

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black //AnyColorYouWant
```

Hope its help!